# export bulk data as excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, export-to-excel

I have tried to export the data as excel file by executing the below query in background (ruby on rails). But, It's taking around 4+ minutes to complete the execution.

Can you anyone suggest me any methodology/concepts to export bulk amount of data from the db by clicking the button. The result of the below query may be exceed the count 50000 (records). When I am clicking the button, it's getting timeout due the large execution.

I'm using nginx + unicorn server for my application (ROR). I tried by increasing the unicorn workers timeout value from 60 to 240 and changed timeout values in nginx also. But no effect.

The below query is kind of view. Query optimize suggestion is always welcome.

```
SELECT temp.id,
       temp.first_name,
       temp.last_name,
       temp.email,
       temp.status,
       temp.pdate,
       temp.dname,
       (CASE WHEN temp.credit IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE temp.credit END) -(CASE WHEN temp.claim IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE temp.claim END) as b ,
       (CASE WHEN temp.claim IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE temp.claim END) as b1
FROM
  (SELECT users.id,
          first_name,
          last_name,
          email,
          status,
     (SELECT to_char((max(purchased_date) + interval '1 year')::date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      FROM purchases
      WHERE users.id = purchases.user_id
        AND type = 0) AS pdate,
     (SELECT name
      FROM owners
      WHERE owners.id=users.owner_id) AS dname,
     (SELECT sum(credits.credit)
      FROM credits
      INNER JOIN purchases ON purchases.id = credits.purchase_id
      WHERE purchases.user_id = users.id
      GROUP BY purchases.user_id) AS credit,
     (SELECT sum(claims.credits)
      FROM claims
      LEFT OUTER JOIN purchases ON purchases.id = claims.purchase_id
      WHERE purchases.user_id = users.id
      GROUP BY purchases.user_id) AS claim
   FROM users) AS TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it like that.

The HTTP request cycle should not include actions that take too long, like the one you are trying to accomplish. It is bad design.

The user should click on export button, and the application should be returning the control back to the user immediately. Then a background job should be handling the export of the data from the database. (You can use tools like `delayed_job`). In other words, the work should be done asynchronously.

The result of the process should be posted back to the user email or to the user dashboard or to some other browser notification.

P.